# why does it loop more then once...am i missing something

Tags: php, foreach

There is only one record in the table so why does it loop like i have 5 table with one letter each

```
$query = "Select * from click_tracker";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$all_clicks = mysql_fetch_array($result);

foreach($all_clicks as $click){
    print "
    <table border=\"1\">
      <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Visit Count</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>{$click['url_destination']}</td>
        <td>{$click['count']}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>";
}
```

here is the table returned

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Location</th>

    <th>Visit Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Visit Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>

    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Visit Count</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tr>

    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Visit Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>h</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>

</table>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Visit Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>

    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th>Visit Count</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) fetches **one** row as an array. When you try to loop over that result with your `foreach`, you are actually looping through all the **columns** of the row you returned (twice, actually, because by default, `mysql_fetch_array` returns an array with both numeric and indexed keys!)

If you want to get **all** the rows in your result set (and you more than likely do), you need to use a while loop to keep fetching rows until there aren't anymore:

```
$all_clicks = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $all_clicks[] = $row;
}
```

and then when you iterate over `$all_clicks`, each iteration will have a complete row.

Comment: +1 for useful description of the acutal problem (i.e the columns)

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_array() returns rows, it looks like your foreach is looping over fields in a row not rows in a result set.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be printing multiple tables. I don't think this is what you intend though. You need to print the table's opening and closing tags, and the headings, outside of the loop. You should also call `mysql_fetch_array()` in the loop and not just once.

```
print "
    <table border=\"1\">
      <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Visit Count</th>
      </tr>";

$query = "Select * from click_tracker";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($click = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print "
      <tr>
        <td>{$click['url_destination']}</td>
        <td>{$click['count']}</td>
      </tr>";
}

print "</table>";
```

You should also consider escaping the data in `$click`, but I don't know what your data looks like so I'm not sure what to put in the area just between the `while` and `print` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this:

```
$query = "Select * from click_tracker";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($click = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Comment: i believe mysql_fetch_array returns an array, hence $all_clicks is an array - $result is a result resource.

Comment: Uhm... The PHP manual says of mysql_fetch_array() "Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead."  In the example `$result` is a resource, not `$all_clicks`

Comment: your code had read `mysql_fetch_assoc($all_clicks)` a couple of seconds before you edited your answer.

Comment: Ohh that. Yes, that was a typo. Now, I got what @Robin meant. Thanks for clearing :) It's been a long day and midnight here :)

Answer (score 0):

do a `print_r($all_clicks)` and check the result is what you expect it to be.

you don't really need to use a foreach if there's only one result.

```
 $query = "Select * from click_tracker";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $all_clicks = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     print "
        <table border=\"1\">
          <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Visit Count</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{$all_clicks['url_destination']}</td>
            <td>{$all_clicks['count']}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>";
```