# How do you create a simple function to query the database? Mine isn't working!

Tags: php, mysql, function

I want to make a simple function that I can call on to query my database. I pass the "where" part of the query to it and in the code below, my $q variable is correct. However, what should I then do to be able to use the data? I'm so confused at how to do something I'm sure is extremely easy. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
function getListings($where_clause)
{
 $q = "SELECT * FROM `listings` $where_clause";
 $result = mysql_query($q,$dbh);
 foreach (mysql_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
  $listingdata[] = $row;
 }
 return $listingdata;
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message or does the function just return a blank?

Comment: whare are you passing to $where_clause? You might need the keyword WHERE

Comment: possible duplicate of [why does it loop more then once...am i missing something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670648/why-does-it-loop-more-then-once-am-i-missing-something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should be like this:

```
function getListings($where_clause, $dbh)
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `listings` $where_clause";

    $result = mysql_query($q, $dbh);

    $listingdata = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        $listingdata[] = $row;

    return $listingdata;
}
```

Improvements over your function:

1. Adds MySQL link `$dbh` in function arguments. Passit, otherwise query will not work.
2. Use `while` loop instead of `foreach`. [Read more here.](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array)
3. Initialize `listingdata` array so that when there is no rows returned, you still get an empty array instead of nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid db connection? You'll need to create the connection (apparently named $dbh) within the function, pass it in as an argument, or load it into the function's scope as a global in order for `$result = mysql_query($q,$dbh);` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `while`, not `foreach`, with [`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array), or else only the first row will be fetched and you'll be iterating over the columns in that row.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `listings` $where_clause";
$result = mysql_query($q,$dbh);
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) != false)
{
  $listingdata[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: That worked for me perfectly!  Now once I have the results, should I just make a foreach statement to put every record in a div?

Answer (score 0):

**Always add error handling in your code**. That way you'll see what is going wrong.

```
    $result = mysql_query($q,$dbh);
    if (!$result) {
            trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()." in ".$q);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which will save you some time. First Argument tablename, then condition(where), fields and the order. A simple query will look like this : query_db('tablename');

```
  function query_db($tbl_name,$condition = "`ID` > 0",$fields = "*",$order="`ID` DESC"){

    $query="SELECT ".$fields." FROM `".$tbl_name."` WHERE ".$condition." ORDER BY".$order;
    $query=$con->query($query);
    $row_data=array();
    while($rows = $query->fetch_array()){
        $row_data[] = $rows;
    }
    return $row_data;
}
```